# Python 3 Grammar: NEWLINE at the end of file or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, grammar

Looking at the [Python 3 Grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), we can see that, using `file_input` as the starting symbol, a valid production could be a single statement. For example, something like:

```
stmt ENDMARKER
```

This would be like having a single literal in a file

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

However, the rules for `stmt -> simple_stmt` require that `stmt`s end in a `NEWLINE`. So, I would assume that a file containing a single literal list and no newline at the end would cause a parsing/syntax error. But it doesn't.

Is python appending a `\n` character to files it parses, or is it always emitting a `NEWLINE` token before `ENDMARKER`?

Comment: A couple of observations. 1) A POSIX text file *always* (by definition) ends with a newline, so this would only be an issue with a file saved by a Windows text editor, which might omit the final newline. 2) At least in CPython, `exec` will append a final newline if necessary (see `Parser/tokenizer.c`).

Comment: I did not know that POSIX text files must end in newlines. That's very interesting. Thank you for the reference to `tokenizer.c` as well. That answers my question fully. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept